# htaccess specific ip

Tags: .htaccess, web

Hey guys I want to allow certain ip's to access my webpage, I have it working for one ip but I want to add another how would I go about this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^217\.20\.17\.210
RewriteRule (.*) http://google.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I thought I would be able to just to duplicate the current line with the ip address and input the new one but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^217\.20\.17\.210
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://google.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Added to allow `123.123.123.123` doesn't work for you?

As an alternative, you could try just using the [Allow/Deny in mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html), such as:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 217.20.17.210
Allow from 123.123.123.123
```

It's a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: Afraid it doesn't work for me, I was reading up that I might need to add a $ after each one but that didn't work

Comment: Ah problem solved, just realized I'm on a shared ip, so the machine I was checking it on had the same i[p as one that was already allowed.